# Is it practical to maintain a long list of calculation parameters in a calculation software system as an enum?

Tags: java, enums, software-design

I am currently maintaining a legacy *calculation software system* in *Java*. There are hundreds of calculations with different names and, each calculation has its own set of *parameters*, most of them are flags indicating some additional sub-calculations. Internally lots of the `if` conditions are controlled by those parameters.

Currently there is a *parameter* table in the database, correspondingly there is an `enum` in the Java code base sth like:

```
public enum Parameter {
    GO_TO_FLOW_A,
    GO_TO_FLOW_B,
    IN_EU_STYLE,
    IN_US_STYLE,
    ROUND
    //there are yet hundreds more enum elements
}
```

The **problem** is that the *parameter* table contains hundreds of rows, i.e. there are hundreds of *parameters* for all the calculations, and this enum contains hundreds of elements. What's even worse is when adding more new *parameters* into the database, the corresponding elements has to be added to the `enum Parameter` as well.

**Question**: Is there any better solution to deal with such many *parameters* in Java? Probably `enum` is not a good choice in this use case?

Answer (score 1):

Since you software was designed to be a calculation software, is reasonable not to put this "parameters" as enums. If you do that, you add a implicit **coupling between your database and your code**, like you said. The question is more complex because you have internal flows that depends on this enums. If you will be redesign the application, maybe it will cost some extra effort of time.

In my point of view, you must think: "What of this calculation behaviors are common to your calculations?", "What are not?". After that, you will be able to extract common behavior into a class or a well know design pattern. The different behavior you could extract into other classes, organized in a way that when you retrieve your "parameter" from the database you will be able to dynamically choose the classes/objects that perform some kind of calculations that you need to use(like one kind for a processing type inside your if etc.) - Here maybe you could use Strategy Pattern.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation. The **coupling between database and code** makes big sense :)

Answer (score 1):

This might be subjective, but in general terms it makes no sense to duplicate the database as enums.

Probably the best course of action is to replace new params with regular classes and let the existing ones untouched for a gradual upgrade.

If possible a full upgrade to get rid of the enums would be better but that depends on the resources you have available.

> Question: Is there any better solution to deal with such many parameters in Java? Probably enum is not a good choice in this use case?

Yes, get rid of the `enum` and use regular classes

class Parameter {
String name;
String value;
}

Or something like that. You didn't show how the enum is used but I think something like the following should work:

```
 Result calculate(List<Parameter> params) {
      ....
 }
```